# Vimeo API invalid token when making request

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, vimeo-api

I am trying to make a request to the Vimeo api v3 using this request URL:

https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query=elvis&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

The token I am sending is copy and pasted from the web interface. I generated it there. I'm trying it from the browser and receiving this response:

```
{
"error": "A valid user token must be passed."
}
```

I know the simple answer is that I copied the token incorrectly but I have tried this multiple times with different tokens and receive the same response. I believe there is something wrong with the way I am making the request.

Comment: I believe you should pass the token in the header of the request. As per [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication), `curl -H "Authorization: bearer <OAUTH_TOKEN>" https://api.vimeo.com`

Comment: 1) How exactly did you obtain the token? 2) As Abm mentioned, the token should go in the header.

Comment: Hey, sorry I am traveling today, I'll give it a try this evening or tomorrow. I obtained the token using the "generate token" button on the #authentication tab of the "My Apps/AppName" section of Vimeo's site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vimeo auth requires you to add an `Authorization` header with the value `Bearer {YOUR TOKEN}` as @AbM and @peeskillet mentioned above.

It's ok to generate the token on the dashboard (as you did) for testing, but you will have to implement the OAuth2 flows for a real app.

(You can also easily test their API using this: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/)

Some services allow you to pass `access_tokens` on a query string (looks like Vimeo supports it, but it is not recommended),. They are often called `access_token`, but it is generally not recommended.

Comment: We do, but it's undocumented. the parameter would be `access_token=xxxxx`. It's not recommended.

Comment: It worked using the `access_token` parameter. I'll be sure to implement the proper OAuth2 flow for the actual app. Thanks a lot guys!